# Fancybox Disabling / Stuck

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I'm running a web, look at this http://scout-katz.web.id/gallery/picture/

The fancybox is stuck either on Chrome or Firefox, i tried to replace it with JetPack Plugin like what i'm using now, but everytime i click on the pictures, it still running the FancyBox (and stuck, of course).

Please anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to eliminate Fancybox and just stick with JetPack? (Which I am not familiar with.) If so, you should get rid of the Fancybox includes in the `<head>` of your page. You have three lines to remove to eliminate Fancybox completely:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scout-katz.web.id/wp-content/themes/doover/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?ver=2.1.1" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://scout-katz.web.id/wp-content/themes/doover/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js?ver=2.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://scout-katz.web.id/wp-content/themes/doover/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=2.1.1'></script>
```

Fancybox will definitely not load if those are removed.